# Manhwa in which the main character is killed by his village priest and wakes up in a giant room where he doesn't age but has to fight for his life

Tags: story-identification, manga

I'm looking for a survival, reborn, revenge manhwa in which the main character is killed by his village priest and wakes up in a giant room where he doesn't age but has to fight for his life every after 10 years.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. I'm unclear on the last part of your description, though. When you say that the main character wakes up in a room where he doesn't age but _"has to fight for his life **every after** 10 years"_, did you mean _every_ 10 years or _after_ 10 years? (Or maybe even _for_ 10 years?) I'd appreciate it if you could clarify what you meant there.